# Sort words and then the sentence including digits and characters in Shell scripting or perl scripting

Tags: c, perl, bash, shell, sorting

I have a string 
`"heya64 this is21 a good89 day91"`

I have to sort in such way that , first each word have to sorted like,
46ahey and then these words need to be sorted with other words. So the result has to be like the one below,

`"12is 19ady 46aehy 89dgoo a hist"`

Can you please tell me how to do this mostly in scripting,bash or perl . If not atleast good algorithm in c language

Comment: 46ahey? Shouldn't that be 46aehy?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Unfortunately, we all make it into one.  FWIW, I wouldn't be surprised to see half a dozen responses to this too.

Comment: @devnull Over two hours and still not closed. That is also the problem.

Comment: I am sorry @JonathonReinhart And devnull , i thought its a nice question only. I happened to get this question all of sudden and started writing perl script. Till splitting and putting into an array i am able think. But not after that. Sorry if i degraded overflow.com by asking such a question.

Comment: @Louis yeah it has to be 46ahey. changing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm to sort this problem is simple, just like you said in your question description, sort characters in each word first, then sort these sorted-word again.

Like this:

```
$ echo heya64 this is21 a good89 day91 | perl -anE 'say(join " ", sort(map { join "", sort split // } @F))'
12is 19ady 46aehy 89dgoo a hist
```